# I am creating a sequential ID number. How can I use Len() function and omit previously dropped frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Very new to python,

I am building a code that creates an upload file for an external system.
One of the requirements is an "Entry Number" column that has a syntax of 101-000000001, 101-000000002, ..., 101-000344539 etc. per row entry.

I am using the below code to build the sequential entries, but I am noticing breaks in the sequence output. My theory is that len() is using the index of the original data vs the new size after I dropped a bunch of frames.

I tried to reset the index, but that isn't working.
Any idea of what I can add or change to get the desired output?

```
## Add new column for the Entry Number
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.insert(0,'ENTRYNUMBER', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
df['ENTRYNUMBER']=df['ENTRYNUMBER'].apply('{:0>9}'.format)
df['ENTRYNUMBER']=('101-'+ df['ENTRYNUMBER'])
```

--

Input Dataframe (df)

| ITEM | DATE | QUANTITY | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2/3/2022 | 7 | CTN |
| A | 2/4/2022 | 8 | CTN |
| B | 2/3/2022 | 15 | CTN |
| B | 2/4/2022 | 16 | CTN |
| C | 2/3/2022 | 21 | CTN |
| C | 2/4/2022 | 25 | CTN |

LookUp Data Frame (df2)

| ITEM |
| --- |
| A |
| C |

Code to Drop any item on df that isn't on df2

```
## Use ItemList to create a new column that flags if the item is on the item list / Anything not on list is dropped / flag column is removed 
df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', indicator=True)
df.drop(index=df[df['_merge'] == 'left_only'].index, inplace=True)
df=df.drop(df.columns[[4]], axis=1)
```

Resulting Dataframe (df)

| ITEM | DATE | QUANTITY | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2/3/2022 | 7 | CTN |
| A | 2/4/2022 | 8 | CTN |
| C | 2/3/2022 | 21 | CTN |
| C | 2/4/2022 | 25 | CTN |

Code to add Entry Number

```
## Add new column for the Entry Number
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.insert(0,'ENTRYNUMBER', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
df['ENTRYNUMBER']=df['ENTRYNUMBER'].apply('{:0>9}'.format)
df['ENTRYNUMBER']=('101-'+ df['ENTRYNUMBER'])
```

Desired Output

| ENTRYNUMBER | ITEM | DATE | QUANTITY | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101-000000001 | A | 2/3/2022 | 7 | CTN |
| 101-000000002 | A | 2/4/2022 | 8 | CTN |
| 101-000000003 | C | 2/3/2022 | 21 | CTN |
| 101-000000004 | C | 2/4/2022 | 25 | CTN |

Current Output

| ENTRYNUMBER | ITEM | DATE | QUANTITY | UOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101-000000001 | A | 2/3/2022 | 7 | CTN |
| 101-000000002 | A | 2/4/2022 | 8 | CTN |
| **101-000000005** | C | 2/3/2022 | 21 | CTN |
| **101-000000006** | C | 2/4/2022 | 25 | CTN |

My theory is the sequence is off because it is counting previously dropped frames

Prior to this code running, a look up is being done with df2 to drop rows in df that aren't matching. This is what I believe is causing the breaks in the entry number sequence.

Comment: you should provide a sample of the data and the expected output

Comment: Sorry about that @mozway  Added reference tables to give a sample of the data & outputs

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use:

```
df.insert(0, 'ENTRYNUMBER', '101-' + (pd.Series(range(len(df)))
                                        .add(1).astype(str)
                                        .str.zfill(9))
         )
```

or a list comprehension:

```
df.insert(0, 'ENTRYNUMBER', [f'101-{i+1:0>9}' for i in range(len(df))])
```

output:

```
     ENTRYNUMBER ITEM       DATE  QUANTITY  UOM
0  101-000000001   A   2/3/2022          7  CTN
1  101-000000002   A   2/4/2022          8  CTN
2  101-000000003   B   2/3/2022         15  CTN
3  101-000000004   B   2/4/2022         16  CTN
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both options are giving me the same result as my initial code.  I believe len is still using the initial shape of the dataframe to get its result. I am going to edit my question to show the dropping that occurs before this code runs. Hopefully that is what is missing.

Comment: This code should not drop any row. Maybe you're doing this afterwards?

Comment: Appreciate your help! When I export the data right after this code, the sequence is off. I added the drop I do before the code in my initial question. Maybe that is the culprit of messing with the sequence?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your process (processing, drop, export to file…)

Comment: Added additional processing information - hopefully that clarifies. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I"d look for scoping and spelling mistakes in the code. This works as expected:

```py
# Make the data frames from your example inputs
from io import StringIO

string = """
ITEM    DATE    QUANTITY    UOM
A   2/3/2022    7   CTN
A   2/4/2022    8   CTN
B   2/3/2022    15  CTN
B   2/4/2022    16  CTN
C   2/3/2022    21  CTN
C   2/4/2022    25  CTN
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep="\t")

string = """
ITEM
A
C
"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep="\t")

# Select only the ITEMs that exist in df2
df = df[df["ITEM"].isin(df2["ITEM"])]

# Add the ENTRYNUMBER column
s = "101-" + pd.Series(np.arange(len(df)) + 1).astype("str").str.zfill(9)
s.index = df.index
df.insert(0, "ENTRYNUMBER", s)
```

Result:

```
     ENTRYNUMBER ITEM      DATE  QUANTITY  UOM
0  101-000000001    A  2/3/2022         7  CTN
1  101-000000002    A  2/4/2022         8  CTN
4  101-000000003    C  2/3/2022        21  CTN
5  101-000000004    C  2/4/2022        25  CTN
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, this still isn't working for me. Before the look up the index matches the number of rows in the data. After the look up, it keeps the same index, but it skips index values for anything left out of the look up.  If len() looks at the shape/index of an object, it is going use the pre-look up shape  not the post look-up shape. The logic in my mind makes me think i need to "reset" the index following the look up. Does that make sense?

Comment: `len()` skips over any gap in the index. It just count the number of rows in the data frame. I suspect an object did not change where you expected it. Place a break point and walk through your code to see where the problem lies